# Using @Formula with a collection in Java / Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently stuck with Hibernate : I want to fetch a String collection using a formula (and join tables)

---

### Environment

- Java 12
- Hibernate 5.3.5.Final
- MariaDB 10.0.29

---

### Database

```
|       Foo       |
|:---------------:|
| id     : String |
```

```
|       Bar       |
|:---------------:|
| id     : String |
| foo_id : String |
| baz_id : String |
```

---

### Hibernate Mapping

No getters / setters / constructors... for clarity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private List<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    private String fooId;

    @Column(name = "baz_id")
    private String bazId;
}
```

(multiple bar for the same foo_id can have the same baz_id)

Now my problem :)

I would like to get in the Foo class a collection (Set or List) of unique bazId for corresponding Bars. I know I could fetch all the Bar and compute the collection in Java but it would be a very expensive operation so I would like to perform it with an SQL query.

I tried to write the following in the Foo class :

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@Formula("SELECT DISTINCT(b.baz_id) FROM bar b WHERE b.foo_id : id")
private Collection<String> bazIds;
```

But I got the following error :

> Table 'database.Foo_bazIds' doesn't exist

How can I achieve to fetch data I want (may be it's not supported by Hibernate, can't find any documentation about @Formula and collections...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use `@Formula` the same way you did, but I came to the conclusion that it's not supposed to work that way. Instead I solved it like this:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "bar", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id"))
@Column(name = "baz_id")
private Set<String> bazIds;
```